# 2D Rotation Transform Matrix Issues

Tags: c++, rotation

I'm stuck on my computer graphics class homework. I'm sorry if this is not right place to ask. I think this is closest thing to computer graphics.

My assignment is to create basic 2D colored polygons at original position and another same polygon transformed to new location.

I am required to implement translation, rotation, scale using transform matrix. I believe I wrote my translation and scale correctly but I think rotation is having issues and I can't seem to figure what's wrong. Can you point out what's wrong?

[image: My Implementation. Untransformed and Transformed images]

This is what image is supposed to look like.

[image: Original Image]

Here's how I did it, I stored 3x3 transform matrix for each polygon. The Driver code provided by my professor, will call transformation functions, translate(x,y), rotate(deg), scale(x,y), and clearTransform(), to modify the matrix of each polygon. It does not modify polygon's vertices until it's the time to render the whole image. When it is time to render, I multiplied the transform matrix with each vertex of the polygon. After the multiplication, I fed the new vertices to drawPoly() function and we get an image.

Here are two functions that I believe works correctly.
Translation code:

```
transform[0][2] = x + transform[0][2];
transform[1][2] = y + transform[1][2];
```

Scale code:

```
transform[0][0] = x * transform[0][0];
transform[1][1] = y * transform[1][1];
```

Now, here's my rotation code.

```
float radian = 0.0174532925;
transform[0][0] = std::cos(degrees*radian) * transform[0][0];
if(transform[0][1] == 0){ 
    transform[0][1] = -(std::sin(degrees*radian));
}else{
    transform[0][1] = -(std::sin(degrees*radian)) * transform[0][1];
}
if(transform[1][0] == 0){
    transform[1][0] = std::sin(degrees*radian); 
}else{
    transform[1][0] = std::sin(degrees*radian) * transform[1][0]; 
}
transform[1][1] = std::cos(degrees*radian) * transform[1][1];
```

So far how I understand it, those 'if' statements are necessary for rotation because the identity(original) transform matrix is supposed to only have ones on middle diagonal and zeros everywhere. If I tried to apply sine functions on that zero, it will remain zero and image will scale instead of rotate.

What's the error in the code that is causing my image to show up incorrectly?

Comment: Sounds like an order of operations problem. The purple star is scaled from the origin *after* it's translated, so the scale affects the translation. Changing the order should address the issue.

Comment: Changing the order of transformations does not affect the transformation.

Comment: A couple of things. (1) Using the `==` operand in floats is not the right way to compare `float` values. Use `if (fabs(vaule) < 0.001)` instead of `transform[0][1] == 0)` and `transform[1][0] == 0)`, to avoid precision errors. (2) Are you overwriting `transform[0][1]` and `transform[1][0]` elsewhere? Why are you accumulating (or updating) values here  `transform[0][1] = -(std::sin(degrees*radian)) * transform[0][1];`? I would use a local transformation matrix each time I apply a transformation.